# Restricting maximum curvature of cubic bezier curve

Tags: analytic-geometry, bezier-curve

Is there any way to reasonably restrict control points of cubic bezier curve so it's oscilating circle will never have radius smaller than `r`?

[Bezier curve with it's oscilating circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUZkd.png)

I need to find the conditions that control points have to meet, so curvature of the bezier is never too large

Comment: Maybe you mean its [sic] *osculating* circle?

Comment: what does [sic] oscilating circle mean?

Comment: The right word is “osculating”, not “oscillating”. The [sic] is Latin for “thus”. Clever people use this as a way to refer to something written (usually incorrectly) by someone else.

Comment: The “hard to tell what you’re asking” comment is nonsense. Your question is quite clear, in my opinion.

Comment: There’s a related question here. But the answers (including mine) are not very helpful. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854757/maximum-curvature-of-2d-cubic-bezier?rq=1